# Return error from php to dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I would like to return an error on a case from my php code that handles the upload.

Currently if the php upload fails the JS still thinks it successes which I presume is to do with the fact it returned fine.

I have tried returning false instead of a string but that still runs the this.on('success') function.

**PHP**

```
public function imageUpload(){
    //Сheck that we have a file

    if((!empty($_FILES["file"])) && ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)) {

      //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
      $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
      $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

      if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
        ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 3500000)) {

        //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
          $newname = '/home/anglicvw/public_html/newdev/app/templates/default/images/testimages/'.$filename;
          //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server

          if (!file_exists($newname)) {

            //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
            if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
               echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
            } else {
               echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
            }
          } else {
             echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." already exists";
          }
      } else {
         echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
      }
    } else {
     echo "Error: No file uploaded";
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

            var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#imagesdropzone', { url: '/admin/imageUpload',
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,});
        });

        Dropzone.options.imagesdropzone = {
            init: function() {
                this.on('success', function( file, resp ){
                  console.log( file );
                  console.log( resp );
                });
                this.on('error', function( e ){
                  console.log('erors and stuff');
                  console.log( e );
                });
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, its right. You have to set an HTTP Header.
Have a look at:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-an-error-returned-by-the-server

If you have an HTTP Error and want to show it in the hover error message of DropzoneJS you can:

```
myDropzone.on("error", function(file, message, xhr) {
    var header = xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText;
    $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message').text(header);
  });
```

(You need jQuery for that code [`$().find();`])

The other way would be to return a JSON error message via PHP:

```
//define text for error message
$output['error'] = 'No Token';

//return right HTTP code
if( $error ){
    http_response_code (401);
}
else{
    http_response_code (200);
}

//set Content-Type to JSON
header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
//echo error message as JSON
echo json_encode( $output );
```

Comment: Thanks thats good. Do you know how I would get the message from the header to then be passed into the hover error message?

Comment: Any ideas on that?

Comment: I have added an event listener to do that

Answer (score 0):

Where does `this.on('success')` take the information about the success/failure of the (internal) PHP upload process?

I guess from the HTTP header's status code, which is 200 (OK) even if the upload failed (it just prints some error text).
I recommend you to set a 500 header if the upload fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use below php code snippet

```
public function imageUpload(){
    //Сheck that we have a file

    if((!empty($_FILES["file"])) && ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)) {

      //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
      $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
      $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

      if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
        ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 3500000)) {

        //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
          $newname = '/home/anglicvw/public_html/newdev/app/templates/default/images/testimages/'.$filename;
          //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server

          if (!file_exists($newname)) {

            //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
            if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
               echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
            } else {
               header('Error: A problem occurred during file upload!', true, 500);
               //echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
            }
          } else {
            header("Error: File ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." already exists", true, 500);
             //echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." already exists";
          }
      } else {
        header("Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload", true, 500);
         //echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
      }
    } else {
      header("Error: No file uploaded", true, 500);
     //echo "Error: No file uploaded";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats good. Do you know how I would get the message from the header to then be passed into the hover error message?

Comment: Any ideas on that?

Comment: At client site, (In your script) use xhr.responseText to get error message.

Comment: That doesnt work as the responseText is blank! I think it gets overridden! At the moment I have a solution where I create a session variable and use that but its a bit nasty!